# Query objects on index IDB

Tags: node.js, indexeddb

It seems like it should be quite simple, but I cannot figure out how to query an object store based on a certain index.

By database is created as such:

```
dbPromise = idb.open(idb_name, idb_version, db => {
  const reviewStore = db.createObjectStore('reviews', {
    keyPath: 'id'
  });
  reviewStore.createIndex('restaurant_id', 'restaurant_id', {unique: false});
});
```

I have created the `reviews` object store with an index on `restaurant_id`.

The data stored looks as such:

```
{
  comment: "Mission Chinese Food has grown...",
  createdAt: 1504095567183,
  id: 1123
  restaurant_id: 1
}
```

However, when I make a `get` call as such:

```
db.transaction('reviews').objectStore('reviews').get('1')...
```

I get the object whose `id` is 1, or nothing, not the `restaurant_id`.

**How do I retrieve an array of objects who match the specified index value?**

Comment: I love that you are doing the nanodegree of udacity/google and I found just the right answer to the question I was wondering... and you're using the same names as me hahaha <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will probably work:

```
db.transaction('reviews').objectStore('reviews').index('restaurant_id').getAll(1)
```

Differences from your attempt:

- You have to explicitly tell it what index to use, otherwise it will query the primary key, as you noticed
- `get` retrieves a single record, but `getAll` retrieves an array of all records that match the query. Old browsers (and the current version of Edge) don't support `getAll`, but there is [a polyfill](https://github.com/dumbmatter/IndexedDB-getAll-shim) if you need it.
- `1` rather than `'1'`, probably was just a typo in your question :)